# Python equivalent of curl command

Tags: python, curl

I got this command from a networking tutorial and I am hoping that I can use `python` to automate it more easily later. The command is `curl -sk -u admin:admin1  GET https://192.168.1.31/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual`.

What would be the exact equivalent of `python` command of the `curl` above?

Comment: You can learn about the `requests` module, I feel it will help you in most commands

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: For your above code:
`response = requests.get('https://192.168.1.31/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual', verify=False, auth=('admin', 'admin1'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the requests module for most of the commands as it is one of the most common web scraping module.

You can refer to official documentary over here:
[Link](https://requests.readthedocs.io/)

And use this [link](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to convert your curl into python, although it wont be accurate every time, but it will help you with initial cases.